# Least squares estimates

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, linear-model

Problem: Suppose we have $Y_{1j}=\beta_1 +\epsilon _{ij}$, $j=1,...,n_1$, $Y_{2j}=\beta_1 +\beta_2 +\epsilon _{ij}$, $j=1,...,n_1$,and $Y_{3j}=\beta_1 -2\beta_2 +\epsilon _{ij}$, $j=1,...,n_2$., where $\epsilon_{ij}$ are $iid$ $N(0,\sigma^2)$ variables. Under what condition on $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the least squares estimates of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ uncorrelated?

My thinking:

I think when $n_1=2n_2$ then the least-squares estimates of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ will be uncorrelated but I don't know how to show it here. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: What does $i$ stand for in $\epsilon_{ij}$?

Comment: @gunes It was not mentioned in the problem statement!